# sportsreference API wrong data issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm using the sportsreference API to get some data but I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or there is an issue with the API. When I pull the data I need with the API it always says the away team won, even on games this is not true for.

Code snippet:

```
from sportsreference.nba.boxscore import Boxscores
from sportsreference.nba.boxscore import Boxscore

# Select range of dates to get boxscores from (year, month, day)
games = Boxscores(datetime(2017, 10, 17), datetime(2017, 10, 20))

# Get boxscore abbreviations to get more detailed game boxscores
boxscore_abvs = []
for key in games.games.keys():
    for i in range(len(games.games[key])):
        boxscore_abvs.append(games.games[key][i]['boxscore'])

# Get more detailed boxscores
df = pd.DataFrame()
for abv in boxscore_abvs:
    game_data = Boxscore(abv)
    temp_df = game_data.dataframe
    df = df.append(temp_df)
```

Sample of wrong output from df (Cavs won this game, API reports Celtics):

```sh
              away_assist_percentage  away_assists  away_block_percentage  away_blocks  away_defensive_rating  ...            losing_name   pace  winner  winning_abbr           winning_name
201710170CLE                    66.7            24                    6.6            4                  102.7  ...    Cleveland Cavaliers   99.3    Away           BOS         Boston Celtics
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue caused by the site changing its HTML layout. Seems like it should be fixed in the `0.6.0` release: https://github.com/roclark/sportsreference/pull/506.

In the meantime, you can install from git to get the fixed version:

```sh
pip install --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/roclark/sportsreference.git@master
```

With that, I get the correct result:

```py
Boxscore('201710170CLE').dataframe[['away_points', 'home_points', 'winning_name']]
#               away_points  home_points         winning_name
# 201710170CLE           99          102  Cleveland Cavaliers
```

Comment: Would doing a force install overwrite the current one I have or would I have 2 separate versions doing it this way?

Comment: It would overwrite the package in your python environment. You can also create a `virtualenv` and install the package from github there.